# MacBook Pro won’t recognize my user name and password

Tags: macos

My MacBook Pro mid 2010 stop recognizing my password or username when ever I try to install software or access security settings. But whenever I power on the computer and it gets to login screen it does accept my password there. I have try to boot to recovery and try to reset the password there but it didn’t show me any drive. Any help will be helpful. [image]

Comment: Are you using FileVault or any other encryption program?

Comment: No.  I didn’t use any encryption program. I just happen

Comment: Your login password and your security rights are two different things.  If you can log in, you haven't forgotten your password.  Not being able to install software comes down to rights and privileges.    Are you an admin on this computer?  Is it managed by another person (like an IT department)?

Comment: No admin. I owned it . Just don’t know why all this is happening because I didn’t set any right and privileges

Comment: No..it's not about you setting them or not setting them.  I'm drawing a critical distinction - you're asking about a lost password when it's not lost (you know it and it obviously works).  The problem is the rights and privileges to install software. So, chasing down a solution for a lost password won't fix your issue.

Comment: Create a new user account and see if you can install software using that account instead. This is just to see if it's an account related issue.

Comment: Already have another account yet the same thing . Even if I want to change date and time it still show the box that require username and password blank.

Comment: Are you swapping keyboards?

Comment: No.  I didn’t swap the keyboard